# How to keep in visual mode after identing by shift+> in vim?

Tags: vim

Current it quits the visual mode after indenting once,which is very annoying.

Comment: For indenting more than once, simply use the `.` key to repeat the last operation

Comment: Using . is good. But sometimes you need to do a different operation with the selected code after indentig, like yanking, for instance. And you have to select all over again, which sucks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the normal mode command `gv` to highlight the previous visual selection. Therefore, you could use the following mappings:

```
:vnoremap < <gv
:vnoremap > >gv
```

The `:vnoremap` command sets up a mapping that will work only in visual mode. You are therefore rebinding the `<` and `>` visual mode commands to perform the indent and immediately re-select the previous visual selection.

Comment: It is not correct. Should use `vnoremap` because `vmap` will recursively map and it would break

Comment: @texasbruce: It works fine for me with vmap, however I have edited the answer (and my own .vimrc) to use vnoremap since it is obviously safer.

Answer (score 11):

Using period "." will repeat the indentation of the previously selected text if it was the newest edit of the text. This does not reselect the text, but does the job just as well.